# JSON: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'values' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pass the value of all the textareas on a page to a JSON table.
For some reason I get a "cannot set value of undefined error", I dont understand since my Json is defined earlier.

Here is the code with the 2 functions.

```
function parseToJson() {
    var json = {};

    $("input.invoice_details").each(function () {
        json[this.id] = $(this).val();
    });

    $("select.invoice_details").each(function () {
        json[this.id] = $(this).val();
    });

    json.categories = {};

    $("textarea.invoice_categories").each(function () {
        if (this.value.trim() !== '') {
            json.categories[this.id].values = splitInput(this);
            json.categories[this.id].label = this.name;
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    generatePreveiw(json);
}

function splitInput(textArea) {
    var input = textArea.value.trim();
    var lines = input.split("\n");
    var array = [];
    $.each(lines, function (indexLine, line) {
        var columns = line.split("\t");
        var obj = {};
        $.each(columns, function (indexColumn, column) {
            var columnName = columnsName.columnsName[indexColumn].name;
            obj[columnName] = column;
        });
        array.push(obj);
    });
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: json.categories[this.id].values = splitInput(this);

Comment: Please show your json data

Comment: `var json = {};` — That isn't JSON. That is a JavaScript object. JSON is an external data format that happens to be inspired by JavaScript literal syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        json.categories[this.id].values = splitInput(this);
        json.categories[this.id].label = this.name;
```

should be:

```
        json.categories[this.id] = {
            values: splitInput(this),
            label: this.name
        };
```

You can't set the properties of an object when you haven't created the object first. You can use this object literal syntax to create the object and its properties in one step.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> json.categories = {};
> ```

You have an empty object

> ```
> json.categories[this.id].values = splitInput(this);
> ```

Now you are trying to access a property called `this.id` from that object.

Since the object doesn't have any properties yet, that will always be `undefined`

You then try to assign `undefined.value = splitInput(this)`, which throws an error.

You need to make sure `json.categories[this.id]` has a value before you can set properties on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access a property of the object stored in json.categories[this.id]. 
Unfortunately it is undefined.
Try the following:

```
function() {
        if (this.value.trim() !== '')
        { 
            //Initialize to an empty object if necessary
            json.categories[this.id] = json.categories[this.id] || {};
            json.categories[this.id].values = splitInput(this);
            json.categories[this.id].label = this.name;
        }
    });
```